# How to copy one directory to many directory using Linux command?

Tags: linux

If I have a directory name '1' (without quotes) and want to copy that directory (with its contents) to  many directories name '2' to '70', how do this using Linux commands?

Comment: Yes, this is off topic question. When I wrote this question, I thought that the question will needs Bash programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so, each copy will only do once, but (in bash at least)

```
for x in $(seq 2 70); do cp -r 1 $x; done
```

should do it

Comment: Here's a link to how to use for loops in bash. It might help to explain how the expression works. http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-for-loop/